# how do I manage deletion with multiple foreign keys to the same table in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database

Say I have a model with a Things table and a table of relationships between the things called ThingRelations. It should not be possible to delete a Thing when there are ThingRelations that point to it. This is how I'm trying to implement that:

```py
from django.db import models

class ThingRelation(models.Model):
    first_thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    second_thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=260)
```

How do I automatically delete a Thing when there are no more ThingRelations pointing to it?

Comment: You could try creating a [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete) signal receiver, then check if the model being deleted is a ThingRelation, and if so, if there are any other ThingRelations pointing to the Thing in question. If not, delete the Thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have such options:

- A routine. It can be made as a [`Command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and something like [`crontab`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Or it could be designed as a [`periodiq`](https://dramatiq.io/cookbook.html) routine. This way you can repeatedly select all `Thing` models which have no relations with `ThingRelation`.
- [`signals.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/) action. This way when entry of `ThingRelation` is deleted, you should check both the `first_thing` and `second_thing` in order to know whether the have any more `ThingRelation` relations pointing to them.
- DB trigger (e.g. for [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html)). The same idea as `signal.py` solution, but on DB level.

Which one should you choose? Depends on details of your exact objective. As for me, I use `periodiq` option on simple cases and DB trigger if I aim on high performance.